# how does pay-per-install work on android?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier

I'm thinking to have a third party to promo my app, and I'll pay them per install. In order to avoid fraud, I need to have a unique ID stored in my database. My problem here is that I can't find a reliable unique ID.

1. IMEI - only works on phone
2. Android ID - can be changed even not a rooted device
3. WLAN MAC - not all devices have wifi, or the device has wifi turned off.
4. Bluetooth MAC - same as above

I know device with root access can easily change the IDs, but let's not worry about it now. I assume no one has a rooted device. How do I get a unique ID???

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into OpenUDID for Android, there doesn't seem to be a better way to do what you want for the time being:

https://github.com/vieux/OpenUDID